# My app only gets the first message i send then stops displaying other nodes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase to store the messages under a randomly generated node , messages are successfully added to this node but, it only displays the first message sent.

Here's my class containing the listeners.

I tried changing the Single event listener in get chat id to a value event listener but it didn't solve the problem.

when I close the chat and open it again it shows the first message only.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mMatchId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MatchId");


    mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("connections").child("matches").child(mMatchId).child("ChatId");
    mDatabaseChat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");

    getChatId();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

    mChatLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mChatLayoutManager);
    mChatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getDataSetChat(), ChatActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);

    mSendEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });

}

private void sendMessage() {

    String sendMessageText = mSendEditText.getText().toString();
    if(!sendMessageText.isEmpty()){
        DatabaseReference newMessageDb = mDatabaseChat.push();
        Map newMessage = new HashMap();

        newMessage.put("createdByUser", currentUserId);
        newMessage.put("text", sendMessageText);

        newMessageDb.setValue(newMessage);

    }
    mSendEditText.setText(null);
}


private void getChatId(){

    mDatabaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                chatId = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                mDatabaseChat = mDatabaseChat.child(chatId);
                getChatMessages();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private void getChatMessages() {

   mDatabaseChat.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               for (DataSnapshot t : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                   String message = null;
                   String createdByUser = null;
                   if (t.child("text").getValue() != null) {
                       message = t.child("text").getValue().toString();
                   }
                   if (t.child("createdByUser").getValue() != null) {
                       createdByUser = t.child("createdByUser").getValue().toString();
                   }

                   if (message != null && createdByUser != null) {
                       Boolean currentUserBoolean = false;
                       if (createdByUser.equals(currentUserId)) {
                           currentUserBoolean = true;
                       }

                       ChatObject newMessage = new ChatObject(message, currentUserBoolean);
                       resultChat.add(newMessage);
                       mChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
}
```

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smJhZ.png)

Comment: are you sure you are getting only one message? log chid added method, i dont see an issue with your code.... maybe your item layout has height match parent.... just see that... try scrolling, if it has height match parent it will not be visible

Answer (score 0):

it is because you first time open the activity and your getChatId() function is called a single time and give you one single id of your single message. and then you pass it on addChildEventListener. so thats y it gives you the single messagr to your recyclerview. if you show ur database schema  i will provide youy more specific query

```
  List<Chat> chatMessageList = new ArrayList<>();; 
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child(Common.CHATS);

    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chatMessageList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                assert chat != null;
                    chatMessageList.add(chat);


                 mChatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(context, chatMessageList);
                 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I added a database Image. under the node "Chat" I have a node which indicates a connection between two users under that exists all the messages available in that connection. what exactly should I change?

Comment: I modified my get messages method and it still only displays the first message.

Comment: one thing more  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);